# mysql connection with vb script (from excel macro)

Tags: mysql, vb.net, excel

Im totally new in vb script.
Im trying to connect with mi local mysql db with this code:

```
Option Explicit
Private CN As ADODB.Connection

Function Connect(Server As String, Database As String) As Boolean

Set CN = New ADODB.Connection
On Error Resume Next

With CN

    .ConnectionString = "Driver={MySQL ODBC 5.3 Driver};Server=" & _
        Server & ";Database=" & Database & _
        ";Uid=user;Pwd=password;"
    .Open

End With

If CN.State = 0 Then
    Connect = False
Else
    Connect = True
End If 
End Function


Function Query(SQL As String)

Dim RS As ADODB.Recordset
Dim Field As ADODB.Field

Dim Col As Long 

Set RS = New ADODB.Recordset
RS.Open SQL, CN, adOpenStatic, adLockReadOnly, adCmdText

If RS.State Then
    Col = 1       
    For Each Field In RS.Fields
        Cells(1, Col) = Field.Name
        Inc Col
    Next Field        
    Cells(2, 1).CopyFromRecordset RS
    Set RS = Nothing
End If
End Function

Function Disconnect()    
CN.Close
End Function

Private Sub SQL_Click()

Dim SQL As String
Dim Connected As Boolean

SQL = "Select * from table1"

Connected = Connect("localhost", "table")

If Connected Then        
    Call Query(SQL)
    Call Disconnect
Else        
    MsgBox "Could Not Connect!"
End If

End Sub
```

Always shows could not conect.
ADODB library is ok, my db parameters works in manual imports from mysql, and the driver version is correct. I cant figured out what is happening...

Some help?

Thanks!!!

Answer (score 0):

It seems like your driver name in the connection string is wrong.

Try:
"Driver={MySQL ODBC 5.3 ANSI Driver}"